# before_channel_entry_save hook

Tags: custom-fields, extension, hook

I am writing an extension on EE 3.5.11 and I am using the before_channel_entry_save hook.  In the EE documentation it says and modifications to the object will be saved. I am doing something like this but no matter what I do my modifications do not get saved. Ideas?

```
public function set_custom_fields($entry, $values)
{
    $customFields = $entry->getCustomFields();

    foreach ($customFields as $field) {
        if (strpos($field->getShortName() === "my_custom_field_name") {
            // I have tried just and also with the line below
            $field->setData('my custom value');

            // I have tried just and also with the line above
            $values[$field->getShortName()] = 'my custom value';
        }
    }
}
```

If I dump the values after this I see that my custom field value has indeed been updated but it is not saved the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was driving me insane but I've figured it out.

You need to edit the `$entry` object (1st parameter of the function) in order for this to work. You can, however, use the 2nd parameter, `$values`, for easy reading of the data.

```
public function before_channel_entry_save( $entry, $values )
{
    // Set value for specific field name
    $entry->setProperty( 'field_name', 'Custom value' );
}
```

`setProperty` will save the field value to the `$entry` object automatically. Nothing needs to be returned for this to take effect.

**Your example**

```
public function set_custom_fields($entry, $values)
{
    $customFields = $entry->getCustomFields();

    foreach ($customFields as $field) {
        if (strpos($field->getShortName() === "my_custom_field_name") {
            $entry->setProperty($field->getShortName(), 'my custom value');
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional info.**

You can view `system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Channel/ChannelEntry.php` for some pointers on what can be done with the `$entry` object (look for `$this->x`). For example:

```
// Get current $entry channel id
$entry_channel = $entry->Channel->getId();

// Check permissions
$entry_permissions = $entry->Author->MemberGroup->can_edit_other_entries;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!  I can't believe it was that easy.  This saved me so much frustration.